# How to convert Java ResultSet to R DataFrame?

Tags: renjin

I want to convert resultset table data to dataframe from Java to R. Get the ResultSet in Java and convert it to R compatible format and use the same as dataframe in R.

Comment: You may want to have look at https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin-dbi/blob/master/RJDBC/src/main/java/org/renjin/cran/DBI/JDBCUtils.java

Comment: Thanks @mjkallen. I am unable to download the required dbi jar from maveen repo. Is there any .jar for this package?